# If a lot of people are leaving a particular team, does this imply that a person should also start looking for other jobs?

Tags: team

Suppose a team originally had 10 people. 5 team members left for other jobs. Does this indicate that a person in the team should also start looking for other jobs?

Comment: Did any of the people say why they are leaving(on or off the record)?

Comment: Over what time frame? If 5 people left on Monday, that's different than 5 people leaving over 5 years, or 5 people leaving over a month or two.

Answer (score 6):

> Suppose a team originally had 10 people. 5 team members left for other
>   jobs. Does this indicate that a person in the team should also start
>   looking for other jobs?

Definitely maybe.

If half a team is leaving because they concluded that it is a sinking ship, and if they are correct, then it might make sense to look for another job.

But if the reasons behind the turnover are less dire, then it could create openings for those left behind to rapidly move up.

In general, I always advise people to keep their resume up to date at all times, and keep their eyes on what is happening within their company, within their personal network, and within their industry.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr answer - (i) first find out why they are leaving, before making any decision. (ii) if you personally are happy, what's the problem?

Just because people are leaving isn't in itself a reason to leave yourself, if you can't see any obvious motivation for them doing so. The reasons that come up over and over again are poor company strategy or financial health, poor relationships within teams, lack of opportunities, dysfunctional methods of working. I'd be very surprised if any of these applied and you weren't aware of it. An alternative explanation is that one has left for better things and has decided to poach former colleagues. There's not a lot you can do about that.

It's also possible that they have acted based on being first to hear rumours of forthcoming layoffs, etc. This can be a very risky strategy as the rumour mill can always be wrong, and also can be self-fulfilling as people in roles who were under threat lay themselves off by jumping first.

If this is your team, and up to this point you've been content, then there's a big chance to step up and fill some of the gaps that have been left, which will get you a lot of kudos (and likely more tangible reward too). Don't be a sheep and blindly follow others out of the door. If you're not content, then by all means look elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is not only a danger, but also an opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Since most people like stability and don't go out of their way to look for a career elsewhere, five out of ten leaving might be more than coincidence. They might have figured out that the pay at your place is low, or they might have figured out that your team might disappear soon.

First, find out if your team with a size of five is feasible anymore, and how much the company needs your team. If they need your team, your job may be safer now since all five members are needed. If they don't need your team, they might decide that a team at half strength isn't useful anymore and cancel whatever your team is doing.

I wouldn't quite say "look around for a new job", but "make sure you are aware what jobs are available elsewhere". And make sure you have a bit of money put aside.